# Is it possible to emit a event within a event listener callback for 'newListener' event in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to emit a event within a event listener callback for 'newListener' event in nodejs?

for eg

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter.EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on('newListener', function(test) {
  eventEmitter.emit('data', 'testing');
  console.log('newListener');
});

eventEmitter.on('data', function(test){
  console.log(test)
});
```

I do see the log entry "newListener" but I don't see the callback for 'data' invoked.

Comment: It is possible to emit an event inside the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `newListener` a new listener is not yet active. Use the [`process.nextTick()`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/):

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter.EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on('newListener', function(event) {
    if (event === 'data') {
        process.nextTick(() => {
            eventEmitter.emit('data', 'testing');
        });
    }
    console.log('newListener', event);
});

eventEmitter.on('data', function(test) {
    console.log('data', test)
});
```